# How to shorten SQL LIKE statement

Tags: sql

How could I shorten the following sql query (where I return rows which start with one of four different strings in column "mycolumn"):

```
select * from mytable where mycolumn LIKE 'xyz%' 
OR mycolumn LIKE 'abc%' 
OR mycolumn LIKE 'def%' 
OR mycolumn LIKE 'gth%'
```

J.

Comment: The short answer is (unfortunately) _no_.  However, there are some insightful questions in the duplicate I linked, please take a look.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Why shorten it? I think the query looks fine as is. If your DBMS supports regular expressions, you may be able to use a single expression in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Just looking for a less complicated statement. Reg expressions wont work in DBMS but this LIKE IN idea is helpful, thanks

Comment: @J.Doe: of course "DBMS" products support regular expressions. However with different levels of completeness - which one **are** you using?

Answer (score 4):

You have some options, although none are necessarily good from a performance perspective.  If all the prefixes are the same length, then:

```
where left(column, 3) in ('xyz', 'abc', 'def', 'ghi')
```

If you are using a database that supports regular expressions:

```
where column ~ '^(xyz|abc|def|ghi)'
```

In this case, `~` is the Postgres syntax for regular expression matching.

Comment: Yes, I also experienced a lower performance (in time) when used a similar statement with SUBSTRING

Answer (score 0):

If your database supports Regex, you could use the below code:

```
select * from mytable where mycolumn ~ '^(xyz|abc|def|gth)'
```

Learning Regex is definitely worth considering if your database supports it, although I would imagine the impact performance isn't great, so it'd be recommended if your query is going to rely on a huge volume of strings.